# How to install OpenLDAP password check module in ubuntu?

Tags: password, ldap, openldap

We recently installed ppolicy module and the related things in our OpenLDAP instance for [password policy](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/ppolicy.html#account-unlock),

However, among them there was no way to set up something that does a password check whenever a new password is set. Then, we were pointed out to [this link](http://ltb-project.org/wiki/documentation/openldap-ppolicy-check-password), where `pwdPolicyChecker` seemed like a module that can solve this issue. But we have no idea how to install this C module in our current Ubuntu OpenLDAP set up. Also, the instructions provided seemed to be more like how the OpenLDAP setup used to be earlier in Ubuntu and not like how it is now with `slapd.d`.

Has anyone done an installation of a C module in  OpenLDAP in the new Ubuntu setup? Any pointers toward that would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must install LDAP extension module to have password quality check feature. There are some other extension modules available for Ubuntu. May this article [Password quality check for OpenLDAP](http://techadminblog.com/openldap-password-quality-check/) help you.

Comment: Well I am aware that such modules exist that do password quality check for LDAP, however my question was more towards how installation can be done of these C modules. And if anyone has done it then a brief outline of steps was what I was looking for.